# Can you write some custom CSS to format web form application accordingly

Tags: html, css, radio-button, textarea, inline-styles

Sorry I am a bit of a novice with this, thank you in advance.

I have used a form building tool (Granicus/ Firmstep forms) to build a form and I am struggling to nail the CSS to get the fields to display how I want. I have generated the form to look exactly how I want it by building the form using HTML. Unfortunately the application doesn't recognise the fields when I use HTML. So someone can complete the form but entries arent populated unless you build the form using the built in field selector.

What I am trying to achieve can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762887/can-you-have-4-in-line-text-area-fields-with-a-radio-button-and-label-above) where I built the form using HTML following the guidance in this question.

This is a of what I'm looking to achieve:

[image: picture]

I can add a custom class to the fields but unfortunately I can't nail the CSS to target the correct fields and display the fields as shown in the link above.

Effectively what I want is 4 text areas side by side and in line. Above each text area there will be a radio button with the options yes and no. On top of the buttons there is a label.

As there are going to be multiple lines I need the CSS to specifically target each set of questions.

When I have inserted the correct fields the HTML generated for the fields on the page without any CSS are shown below. I can't amend the HTML, I can only add CSS to manipulate the fields. There is no custom editor that allows the user to inject CSS, the CSS must be coded in manually.

On a side note can I add a placeholder using css?

```html
<span data-name="statictext7" data-type="staticText" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 fieldInput content staticText non-input ">
  <div>
    <span style="font-size: 12pt;"><strong>Q1) Question 1</strong></span>
  </div>
</span>

<div class="field" data-field-name="perviousPositionButton" data-field-type="radio"><div class="fieldContent">
  <label for="perviousPositionButton" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName alignAbove      ">
    <span class="_fieldName">Pervious position</span>
  </label>
  <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 "></div>
    <fieldset name="perviousPositionButton" id="perviousPositionButton" data-name="perviousPositionButton" data-type="radio" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Pervious position" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     alignAbove fieldInput selectInput radio horizontal " data-mandatory-message="This field is required">
      <legend class="hidden">Pervious position</legend>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="perviousPositionButton-0-AF-Field-b8ed31df-0be1-452c-a27d-581bcb225c6f-98ecfb9681" name="perviousPositionButton" value="yes" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="perviousPositionButton-0-AF-Field-b8ed31df-0be1-452c-a27d-581bcb225c6f-98ecfb9681">Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="perviousPositionButton-1-AF-Field-b8ed31df-0be1-452c-a27d-581bcb225c6f-98ecfb9681" name="perviousPositionButton" value="no" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="perviousPositionButton-1-AF-Field-b8ed31df-0be1-452c-a27d-581bcb225c6f-98ecfb9681">No</label>
      </span>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="previousTargetButton" data-field-type="radio">
  <div class="fieldContent">
    <label for="previousTargetButton" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName alignAbove      ">
      <span class="_fieldName">Target set at last meeting</span>                
    </label>
    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 "></div>
    <fieldset name="previousTargetButton" id="previousTargetButton" data-name="previousTargetButton" data-type="radio" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Target set at last meeting" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     alignAbove fieldInput selectInput radio horizontal " data-mandatory-message="This field is required">
      <legend class="hidden">Target set at last meeting</legend>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="previousTargetButton-0-AF-Field-abb50bb1-f009-41c5-9218-948db13dfe77-98ecfb9681" name="previousTargetButton" value="yes" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="previousTargetButton-0-AF-Field-abb50bb1-f009-41c5-9218-948db13dfe77-98ecfb9681">Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="previousTargetButton-1-AF-Field-abb50bb1-f009-41c5-9218-948db13dfe77-98ecfb9681" name="previousTargetButton" value="no" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="previousTargetButton-1-AF-Field-abb50bb1-f009-41c5-9218-948db13dfe77-98ecfb9681">No</label>
      </span>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="currentPositionButton" data-field-type="radio">
  <div class="fieldContent">
    <label for="currentPositionButton" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName alignAbove     ">
      <span class="_fieldName">Current Position</span>
    </label>
    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 "></div>
    <fieldset name="currentPositionButton" id="currentPositionButton" data-name="currentPositionButton" data-type="radio" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Current Position" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     alignAbove fieldInput selectInput radio horizontal " data-mandatory-message="This field is required">
      <legend class="hidden">Current Position</legend>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="currentPositionButton-0-AF-Field-0718de73-1544-47e4-ac16-d27b800a54f1-98ecfb9681" name="currentPositionButton" value="yes" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="currentPositionButton-0-AF-Field-0718de73-1544-47e4-ac16-d27b800a54f1-98ecfb9681">Yes</label>
      </span>
      <span class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" id="currentPositionButton-1-AF-Field-0718de73-1544-47e4-ac16-d27b800a54f1-98ecfb9681" name="currentPositionButton" value="no" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off">
        <label class="radio-label btn" for="currentPositionButton-1-AF-Field-0718de73-1544-47e4-ac16-d27b800a54f1-98ecfb9681">No</label>
      </span>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="targetSetButton" data-field-type="radio"><div class="fieldContent"><label for="targetSetButton" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName alignAbove        "><span class="_fieldName">Target for next meeting</span>               </label>    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 "></div><fieldset name="targetSetButton" id="targetSetButton" data-name="targetSetButton" data-type="radio" role="radiogroup" aria-label="Target for next meeting" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     alignAbove fieldInput selectInput radio horizontal " data-mandatory-message="This field is required"><legend class="hidden">Target for next meeting</legend><span class="radio-wrapper">   <input type="radio" id="targetSetButton-0-AF-Field-43bae0a1-0dca-4982-8a61-0d34728bfd27-98ecfb9681" name="targetSetButton" value="yes" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off"><label class="radio-label btn" for="targetSetButton-0-AF-Field-43bae0a1-0dca-4982-8a61-0d34728bfd27-98ecfb9681">Yes</label></span><span class="radio-wrapper">    <input type="radio" id="targetSetButton-1-AF-Field-43bae0a1-0dca-4982-8a61-0d34728bfd27-98ecfb9681" name="targetSetButton" value="no" required="true" class="radio2 " autocomplete="off"><label class="radio-label btn" for="targetSetButton-1-AF-Field-43bae0a1-0dca-4982-8a61-0d34728bfd27-98ecfb9681">No</label></span></fieldset><div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div></div> </div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="previousTarget" data-field-type="textarea"><div class="fieldContent textAreaColumn"><label for="previousTarget" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName hide hideLabel        "><span class="_fieldName">Pervious position</span>             </label>    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><textarea data-name="previousTarget" id="previousTarget" name="previousTarget" data-type="textarea" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     hideLabel fieldInput textarea " data-mandatory-message="This field is required" data-min-message="Please input at least _min_value_ characters" data-max-message="Please input no more than _max_value_ characters" data-validation-mask-message="Please input text of the format: _validation_mask_" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 70px;"></textarea><div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div></div> </div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="previousTarget" data-field-type="textarea"><div class="fieldContent textAreaColumn"><label for="previousTarget" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName hide hideLabel        "><span class="_fieldName">Target set at last meeting</span>                </label>    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><textarea data-name="previousTarget" id="previousTarget" name="previousTarget" data-type="textarea" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     hideLabel fieldInput textarea " data-mandatory-message="This field is required" data-min-message="Please input at least _min_value_ characters" data-max-message="Please input no more than _max_value_ characters" data-validation-mask-message="Please input text of the format: _validation_mask_" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 70px;"></textarea><div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div></div> </div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="previousTarget" data-field-type="textarea"><div class="fieldContent textAreaColumn"><label for="previousTarget" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName hide hideLabel        "><span class="_fieldName">Current Position</span>              </label>    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><textarea data-name="previousTarget" id="previousTarget" name="previousTarget" data-type="textarea" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     hideLabel fieldInput textarea " data-mandatory-message="This field is required" data-min-message="Please input at least _min_value_ characters" data-max-message="Please input no more than _max_value_ characters" data-validation-mask-message="Please input text of the format: _validation_mask_" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 70px;"></textarea><div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div></div> </div>

<div class="field" data-field-name="previousTarget" data-field-type="textarea"><div class="fieldContent textAreaColumn"><label for="previousTarget" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11  fieldName hide hideLabel        "><span class="_fieldName">Target for next meeting</span>               </label>    <div class="af-block col-xs-1 col-sm-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div><textarea data-name="previousTarget" id="previousTarget" name="previousTarget" data-type="textarea" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11     hideLabel fieldInput textarea " data-mandatory-message="This field is required" data-min-message="Please input at least _min_value_ characters" data-max-message="Please input no more than _max_value_ characters" data-validation-mask-message="Please input text of the format: _validation_mask_" autocomplete="off" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 70px;"></textarea><div class="screen-reader-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></div></div> </div>
```

Comment: instead of asking multiple question to an overall same question, make a plan on how the layout should be, draw a picture of your intend layout and add this instead. Then we can help you to get the layout done instead of makign an efford to anwser multiple questions. And as personal note, I got no review of my anwser to the last question from you. So I'm not sure if I want to make the efford again to anwser over and over...

Comment: I have added a picture to my original question.  All I need is some guidance on CSS to target the fields on the form so it looks like what I have done in the picture. The CSS used to achieve the above was done in conjunction with building the form using HTML. But I need to build the form using the form builder elements. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> On a side note can I add a placeholder using css?

Yes, you can.
If you want to do that inside the **text-area**, add:

```
<textarea placeholder="Some text..."></textarea>
```

And if you want to do that outside, just create some **html classes** and add **css**.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick when put in HTML. Can you add a placeholder using CSS?